# I need help in python while making a program

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import requests

def listen_to_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    return r.recognize_google(audio)

def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def main():
    speak("Hello! How can I assist you today?")

    while True:
        try:
            user_input = listen_to_audio().lower()
            print("You said:", user_input)

            if "weather" in user_input:
                speak("I can check the weather for you. Please provide the location.")
                location = listen_to_audio()
                weather_url = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={location}&appid=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"
                response = requests.get(weather_url)
                data = response.json()
                temperature = data["main"]["temp"]
                weather_description = data["weather"][0]["description"]
                speak(f"The temperature in {location} is {temperature} Kelvin with {weather_description} weather.")
            elif "exit" in user_input:
                speak("Goodbye!")
                break
            else:
                speak("I didn't understand. Please try again.")

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            speak("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Please repeat.")
        except sr.RequestError:
            speak("I'm sorry, there was an issue with my speech recognition.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sathy/OneDrive/Desktop/Chatbot.py", line 1, in 
import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'

To make a chat bot with voice recognition

Comment: So you are creating a chat bot with voice recognition but you got stuck at `ModuleNotFoundError` problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is explicit: `No module named 'speech_recognition'`.

You're missing a Python module.

To install it:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

If you don't have `pip`, to install it on Windows:

```
py -3 -m ensurepip
```

---

Sources:

- https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/
- [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)